# Created new Fedora 37 VM with 1 TB but df shows 15 GB

Tags: linux, partitioning, fedora, storage, dev

This morning, I created a virtual machine with 1 TB of storage through VMware, I verified on initial install that the 1TB disk was selected and ran the installation, went through the initial configuration, I looked at the space to confirm the correct size and found that the root drive only has 15 GB of space as shown below

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1.6G  1.1M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   15G  1.8G   14G  12% /
tmpfs                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /tmp
/dev/sda2                960M  215M  746M  23% /boot
tmpfs                    795M     0  795M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Running fdisk -l shows me that the 1 TB of storage was allocated to /dev/sda or /dev/sda3

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1 TiB, 1099511627776 bytes, 2147483648 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6E74A81B-1A8B-4AE1-983F-2C06430342C1

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096    2101247    2097152    1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2101248 2147481599 2145380352 1023G Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 15 GiB, 16106127360 bytes, 31457280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/zram0: 7.76 GiB, 8328839168 bytes, 2033408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

My question is, how do I utilize this storage? I'd like it to be mounted at root, but I can't seem to do so. Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: You will want to look into `lvresize` and make sure you use the `-r` option.

Comment: So having downvoted my answer, please provide an answer that tells the OP how to pre-allocate 1 TB with slices.

Comment: lvresize doesn't seem to work, hasn't actually changed the drive.

Comment: The answer I provided (now downvoted and deleted) will fix your issue.

Comment: John, Could you please provide your answer once more? I don't know who downvoted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if I'm late to the party, but I just encountered this issue, so here's a fix!

### TL;DR

For a default Fedora Server 38 installation:

```sh
$ sudo lvextend --extents +100%FREE /dev/mapper/fedora-root
$ sudo xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/fedora-root
```

Done, no reboot required.

### Details

By default, even for a fresh install, Fedora Server only uses 15GB of storage for the main partition.
(I remember reading somewhere it was possibly for compatibility reasons, but don't quote me on this...).
That being said, since your installation uses LVM, you can easily resize the selected partition using `lvextend`.

Like you, I had a 1TB SSD with a 15GB main partition:

```
$ sudo df

Filesystem               1K-blocks     Used  Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                      4096        0       4096   0% /dev
tmpfs                      3944956        0    3944956   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      1577984     1340    1576644   1% /run
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   15663104 15662396        708 100% /
tmpfs                      3944960        0    3944960   0% /tmp
/dev/sda2                   983040   286932     696108  30% /boot
/dev/sda1                   613160     7196     605964   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                       788988        4     788984   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                       788988        4     788984   1% /run/user/1001
```

(Note: use `df -h` or `df --human-readable` for shorter numbers)

---

1. Use `lvextend` to resize the partition and use 100% of the remaining free space:

```sh
$ sudo lvextend --extents +100%FREE /dev/mapper/fedora-root

Size of logical volume fedora/root changed from 15.00 GiB (3840 extents) to 929.92 GiB (238060 extents).
Logical volume fedora/root successfully resized.
```

2. Normally, you should be able to use `resize2fs` to apply this change to the selected filesystem, or simply pass `-r`/`--resizefs` during the previous step:

```sh
$ sudo lvextend --extents +100%FREE /dev/mapper/fedora-root
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/fedora-root
```

or, back during step 1:

```sh
$ sudo lvextend --resizefs --extents +100%FREE /dev/mapper/fedora-root
```

But for me, it didn't work.
With a default Fedora Server 38 installation, `resize2fs` gave me this:

```sh
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/fedora-root

resize2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/fedora-root
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Here's the catch: by default, Fedora Server uses XFS instead of BTRFS like Fedora Workstation (or ext4 like other distributions).
So, the equivalent is this:

```
$ xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/fedora-root
meta-data=/dev/mapper/fedora-root isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=983040 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1, sparse=1, rmapbt=0
         =                       reflink=1    bigtime=1 inobtcount=1 nrext64=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=3932160, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0, ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=16384, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data blocks changed from 3932160 to 243773440

$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs                    3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1.6G  1.3M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/fedora-root  930G   22G  909G   3% /
tmpfs                    3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /tmp
/dev/sda2                960M  281M  680M  30% /boot
/dev/sda1                599M  7.1M  592M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                    771M  4.0K  771M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Hope this helps!